# Passing extra argument to Sanic's post

Tags: python, post, python-requests, sanic

The situation is that I have got someone's code who left my office. He has used Sanic framework. Now, the client has requested some changes. I have to send an additional data to server which will be stored in the database and later can be retrieved.

Code:

The code earlier was:

```
def send_update_to_server(v_Number, state, server_url):
  data = {'state': state}
  address_to_send = "http://{}/vote/{}".format(server_url, v_Number)
  r = requests.post(address_to_send, json=data)
```

So, to send the additional data, I added the variable i want to send:

```
def send_update_to_server(v_Number, state, server_url, new_number):
  data = {'state': state}
  address_to_send = "http://{}/vote/{}".format(server_url, v_Number)
  r = requests.post(address_to_send, new_number, json=data)
```

The post method on Sanic side is:

```
async def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  //some_code
```

Now, I am not able to retrieve the new_number that I sent from my code using requests.post. Can anyone help me in this? I am pretty new to server side programming and especially Sanic. I would be glad to provide additional code if required.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution so I have decided to go for a workaround. I will send new_number appended with v_number and I will separate them on server side and perform required operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the json data sent to a Sanic endpoint is available as `request.json`, see [docs](https://sanicframework.org/en/guide/basics/request.html#json).

So, it looks like you just need to do something like this:

```py
def send_update_to_server(v_Number, state, server_url, new_number):
  data = {'state': state, 'new_number': new_number}
  address_to_send = "http://{}/vote/{}".format(server_url, v_Number)
  r = requests.post(address_to_send, json=data)
```

Then, you can read it in your handler:

```py
from sanic.response import text
async def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return text(request.json.get("new_number"))
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your answer. It worked for me. I have another question if you can help me on that please. As you see above, the post request is being sent with "Vote/v_Number". On backend side, the get request is also like that which expects "v_Number". But I want the v_Number earlier posted through post request when I send get request. Do I need to create another route for that? Currently the v_number from post request is getting stored in mongo database which uses motor(of which again I have not much idea how to retrieve values).

Comment: If you want to send a message on https://community.sanicframework.org/ we can have a more involved discussion.

Comment: I will try some things and get back to you on this if I am unable to make it work. Thanks for your help again. :)